# angular 4 deployment package refreshing error server in apache server

Tags: angular, apache

**Currently**, my angular  app run apache server in 'http://localhost' root or index page, but when refreshing the inner page 'http://localhost/dms-data/summary-of-findings' then show browser

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /dms-data/summary-of-findings was not found on this server.**

---

**Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80**

this message in my browser 
my index.html base href is

```
<base href="http://localhost/">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196132/getting-404-error-on-page-refresh-in-angular-4/47196213#47196213 can you check this

Comment: i think it's issue in your apache configuration

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using HTML pushState as location strategy due to which when you refresh from browser, the browser sends request of your routed page to apache server. As apache server is unaware of this internal routing by angular due to it shows 404 error.

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. **Define fallback page as index.html**: You need to configure this in server due to which any unknown page request (which is your routed request) send to your server will be redirected to your main html viz. index.html ([See this link](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) for configuring your server)
2. **Use Hash based location strategy**: Using this you won't need any server configuration.Moreover your routed page URL would be like localhost/#/route1. If you're building a website then it may also hamper SEO. ([See this link](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) for more info)

Answer (score 1):

you can create **.htaccess** file in your project directory and put this code into your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

You can check all step to deploy angular build on apache server [Deploy step](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2)

Comment: I'm created .htaccess  file in my root directory on near index.html file but it does not work.