# Angular routing works locally but not when uploaded to cloud

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, typescript, routes

I have an Angular project and while serving it locally, the the routing seems to behave as supposed to but when I release it to the cloud, only *home* route seems to be working while others produce the following error message.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I've tried setting the flag for base href (*ng build --prod --baseHref "./"*) with no difference at all. Not sure how to troubleshoot it at the moment. My routing is set in a separate module like this.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent, RegisterComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent } from "./admin/admin.module";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "admin/register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "admin/login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "**", component: ErrorComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I eliminated my routing setup as  asource of the error since *HomeComponent" is being routed to properly (I can see the contents of its template, since *index.html* is empty except for the app tag). Other than that, I can't proceed because I don't know what to google for since my diagnostic is "won't work, no idea why".

What can I do to resolve it or, at least, to get more info on the issue by e.g. reproducing it locally?

**edit based on comments**

I added *web.config* file with the contents below, according to the links provided by one of the comments.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The behavior now is that no route works at all - I get the original message for any link. So it's consistently misbehaving.

Comment: did you configure index fallback?

Comment: @fatemefazli Are you referring to the pokemon route (catch 'em all)? Yes, the last line in my routes definition: *path:"\*\*", component:ErrorComponent*.

Comment: Not in the Angular app (we can see that), *in the web server*. For the routing to be carried out by the front end the backend needs to respond with `index.html` for any request. Given that you don't show how you've deployed and configure the app in prod we can't tell you exactly what you need to do, but search "push state routing" for whatever server you're running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4 deployment pakage refreshing error server in apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427973/angular-4-deployment-pakage-refreshing-error-server-in-apache-server)

Comment: see [Fallback configuration examples](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

Comment: Is the server url something like `http://abc.xyz/sitename/`? If so, you'll need to use `ng build --prod --base-href /sitename/`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, it's serving *index.html* because I get the */home* route correctly. Or so I figure. It's deployed to Azure and I made sure to push in *web.config* so it's hosted as a .NET Core app but with only a single HTML document.

Comment: @V.S It's at the root, actually, so the URL is *blabla.azurewebsites.net*. No slashy or anything after that.

Comment: check the IIS section of @fatemefazli comment

Comment: Note *"for any request"*. At the moment it seems like you're describing a situation where it only responds with the index file for the home route. Hence the need for configuration; please read the linked resources.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, we've found **something** to work with. Apparently, the *web.config* was gone (I must have removed it without realizing it). After I've added it with contents as shown in the edit in my question, I get the original error for **every** route, i.e. including the one that behaved well previously. So at least we have consistent behavior. Any thoughts on that? I'll start googling on what I have now, meanwhile.

Comment: @fatemefazli I wasn't aware of the fallback thingy - thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, now that I have followed the guide you pointed to, I still don't get anything. Is there a way to verify that the server serves *index.html* to make sure that it's not the issue? I pasted straight off from the site but I tested also with other *web.config*s that I've found while googling. Same result...