# Fallback page for routing in Angular hosted in Azure won't work

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, typescript, routes

I have configured my IIS server in Azure defining fallback page as *index.html* according to [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) and following [the suggestion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428391/8744999). The deployment is carried out based on [this blog about Angular in Azure](https://medium.com/@flu.lund/setting-up-a-ci-pipeline-for-deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-f686c8f190cf). It was said in the docs that one should prefer not to use hash stragegy unless absolutely required. So I've made sure to have  in *index.html* and added  *web.config* as shown below.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Sadly, although the local serving works as expected, the uploaded version won't producing the error below.

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I'm not sure on how to troubleshoot it deeper, despite some hints I've received on my previous question (that led to the realization that I'm in need to configure fallback page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your app could work on your local side, but it did not work after deployed to azure web app. For this situation, you'd better [enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to retrieve the detailed error to narrow down this issue. And you could also update your question with the detailed error for us to troubleshoot this issue.